# IIS-Hosted WebAPI Stops Processing RabbitMQ-Queued Messages

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, asp.net-web-api2

I have a C# WebAPI that is hosted in IIS that listens to a RabbitMQ queue. When the Application Pool is started, it seems the processing of queued messages functions as expected. After a period of time, though, it appears as though the service stops picking up the messages from the queue. I am suspecting that its IIS putting the thread for the app pool to sleep or some such thing but not certain. Is there a way to ensure that the thread and the connection to RabbitMQ is not suspended to confirm? Also, if this is a known issue and my suspicion is incorrect (that its an IIS issue), please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

From a thread entitled "[.NET Core 3.1 Web Consumer -IIS (RabbitMQ)](https://medium.com/@ergin.celik/net-core-3-1-web-consumer-iis-rabbitmq-b1e9d20fd74a)", it turns out I was correct. IIS was suspending the thread for the application pool. Changing the **.NET CLR Version** to **v4.0** instead of No Managed Code, **Start Mode** to **AlwaysRunning**, and **Idle Time-out (minutes)** to **0** resolved my issue. Adding  the **Application Initialization** Windows Feature required a restart of the server.